# Second order differentiation equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find every solution to $y′′ − 6y′ + 5y = e^t$

**My Solution**

I first got my null solution which gave me

$$c_1(e^t) + c_2(e^5t)$$

However, I don't how to find the particular for $e^t$

The answer should look like this:

$$c_1e^t + c_2e^5t −\frac{1}{4}t*e^t$$

Answer (score 0):

When you have a member $e^{at}$ on the right hand side which is already a solution to the homogeneous equation (so $a$ is a root of the char equation) then a standard trick is to search for solutions of the form $t e^{at}$. It is a bit similar to the situation when you have a double root of the char equation. Then already for the solutions of the homogeneous equation you should look for solutions of the form $t e^{at}$.

Answer (score 0):

In
$y′′ − 6y′ + 5y = e^t
$,
suppose
$y(t)
=e^t f(t)
$.

Then
$y'
=e^t(f+f')
$
and
$y''
=e^t(f+2f'+f'')
$,
so
$e^t
=e^t(f+2f'+f''-6(f+f')+5f)
=e^t(-4f'+f'')
$.

Therefore
$f''-4f'=1
$.
A particular solution to this
is seen to be
$f(t) = -\frac14 t
$,
so a particular solution is
$=\frac14 t e^t
$.